# PHPUnit 3.5.14 by Sebastian Bergmann. unrecognized option --log-xml

Tags: php, netbeans, phpunit

i am trying to use netbeans for unit testing. But it is giving me this error. anyone can tell me what is wrong in it?

```
PHPUnit 3.5.14 by Sebastian Bergmann. unrecognized option --log-xml
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the [PHPUnit 3.4.x => 3.5 change log](https://github.com/sebastianbergmann/phpunit/blob/3.5/ChangeLog.markdown) (at the bottom):

> The --log-xml switch has been removed, please use --log-junit instead.

Current Versions of Netbeans (`7.0.x`) work with the old `PHPUnit 3.5.*` and the new versions `3.6.x` so the issue might come from you having configured some custom switches or using and old netbeans version.

Upgrading netbeans and phpunit should solve that